# Why do some Christians believe it was a pole and not a cross?

Tags: life-of-jesus, crucifixion

If you learn some history about the Roman Empire then you will learn that they used to crucify subjects in the conquered territories. The might of the Roman Empire reached the Germanic tribe called the Cherusci and it is well documented that the style of object used to crucify was a cross with two bars intersecting at an angle of 90 degrees. Since it is the Roman soldiers who crucified Jesus, then it follows the same style applied to subjects in other territories was also used on **Jesus**. Israel was a Roman province called **Judaea**.

Why do some believers think it was a pole when indeed it was a cross? If it's a pole then it means both hands were nailed to the top of the pole and not apart like it would be on the cross.